# How can i stop a flexbox item from moving?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so I tried to create a signup page, displayed as a flex, so in the left I'll have some "welcome ..etc" text and in the right the signup form. I also have a JS script so that whenever an input from the form isn't "good", a `<small>` message would show below the input; The problem is that whenever the script is executed, and a `<small` message shows up, my flex is resized and the message from the left side is moved down a bit. Is there anyway to achieve this without using `position: sticky`?

I'll post here a code snippet and 2 photos;

**Code**

```js
function myFunction(input) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("message");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = "te pup dulce";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: rgb(206, 212, 212);
  color: #1c1e21;
}

.container {
  padding: 50px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container h1 {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

#parent1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

small {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1> salll </h1>
  </div>
  <section class="container">
    <div>
      <h1> message </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="parent1">
      <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"> tap me </button>
      <small class="message"></small>
      <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"> tap me </button>
      <small class="message"></small>
      <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"> tap me </button>
      <small class="message"></small>
      <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"> tap me </button>
      <small class="message"></small>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```

[image: before_script:]
[image: after script:]

I know this is pretty basic but i tried almost everything (except sticky cause i don't want that) and can't figure this out ;

Comment: 1 way is to add margin equal to height of message beforehand and  `position: absolute` to message

Comment: That wouldn't go really as expected, as the margin would still apply when the message shows up (so margin will be after the button and before the message), thus making items to resize, and again, making the text on the left to move down

Comment: Also `id` must be unique, you can't have same `id` for diff. elements

Comment: Yup here comes the absolute into work, just have to add containers to them

Comment: fyi, `<small>` is deprecated

Comment: @Rana, thanks a lot, it makes sense now. I thought there is some way to sort this out just by using flex properties and not modifying the `position` attribute of the element. Thanks. Also, @RedGuy11, thank you for your tip, in the original code i made a `<p>` with a smaller font, but as i said, this problem drove me crazy and after many tries i said i'll come here and figure this out fast so for this snippet it seemed a faster solution. Thank you tho. (had no idea it's not used anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a predefined height for `<small>` will work out

> As mentioned in comments that `<small>` is deprecated, you can use other containers for the message like `div` `span`....

```js
function myFunction(input) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("message");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = "te pup dulce";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: rgb(206, 212, 212);
  color: #1c1e21;
}

.container {
  padding: 50px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container h1 {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

#parent1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

small {
  color: red;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1> salll </h1>
  </div>
  <section class="container">
    <div>
      <h1> message </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="parent1">
      <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"> tap me </button>
      <small class="message"></small>
      <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"> tap me </button>
      <small class="message"></small>
      <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"> tap me </button>
      <small class="message"></small>
      <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"> tap me </button>
      <small class="message"></small>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```